# Grabbing pixel attributes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pixel

I am using Python3 on Windows 7. I want to grab all the attributes like color intensity, color etc. Of all the pixels of the screen area that I select with mouse. The selection can be of any shape but right now rectangular and square will do.
I want to do it in any area of the screen.

Can you guys please guide me how to do that in Python?

PS: If the method can work across all the platforms that would be much more appreciated.

Thanks,
Aashiq

Comment: Any Reason Why Your Post Is Written In Title Case?

Comment: I Am Very Much Used To It. It Happens Unconsciously :)

Comment: Fixed. It makes it extremely hard to read, you should really get unused to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of cross-platform GUI toolkit, such as GTK or KDE, maybe Tk or wx will work as well, I don't know.

How you then do it depends on what toolkit you choose.

Comment: I want to be able to do so anywhere be it my desktop screen or any other application window, will those platforms be able to help me with this?

Comment: @AashiqHussain: I don't know, and that's a different question that you should post as a separate question, so that somebody who knows Tk can answer it. They won't see the question if you post it in a comment, so it will never be answered like that.

Comment: @AashiqHussain: Did you not understand my last comment? Don't pose new questions in a  comment. Nobody except me will notice. **Post a new question!**